# Undo with eraser stroke issue

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am erasing the canvas drawing 1 time then Undo works fine, but when I erase more than 1 time then the Undo work as a line stroke, it works for the last step to erase but other are working as line stroke please see below code:

```js
function Sketchpad(config) {
  // Enforces the context for all functions
  for (var key in this.constructor.prototype) {
    this[key] = this[key].bind(this);
  }

  // Warn the user if no DOM element was selected
  if (!config.hasOwnProperty('element')) {
    console.error('SKETCHPAD ERROR: No element selected');
    return;
  }

  this.element = config.element;

  // Width can be defined on the HTML or programatically
  this._width = config.width || $(this.element).attr('data-width') || 0;
  this._height = config.height || $(this.element).attr('data-height') || 0;

  // Pen attributes
  this.color = config.color || $(this.element).attr('data-color') || '#000000';
  this.penSize = config.penSize || $(this.element).attr('data-penSize') || 5;

  // ReadOnly sketchpads may not be modified
  this.readOnly = config.readOnly ||
                  $(this.element).attr('data-readOnly') ||
                  false;
  if (!this.readOnly) {
      $(this.element).css({cursor: 'crosshair'});
  }

  // Stroke control variables
  this.strokes = config.strokes || [];
  console.log(this.strokes)
  this._currentStroke = {
    color: null,
    size: null,
    lines: [],
  };

  // Undo History
  this.undoHistory = (!bErasing) ? (config.undoHistory || []) : [];

  // Animation function calls
  this.animateIds = [];

  // Set sketching state
  this._sketching = false;

  // Setup canvas sketching listeners
  this.reset();
}

//
// Private API
//

Sketchpad.prototype._cursorPosition = function(event) {
  return {
    x: event.pageX - $(this.canvas).offset().left,
    y: event.pageY - $(this.canvas).offset().top,
  };
};

Sketchpad.prototype._draw = function(start, end, color, size) {
  this._stroke(start, end, color, size, 'source-over');
};

Sketchpad.prototype._erase = function(start, end, color, size) {
  this._stroke(start, end, color, size, 'destination-out');
};

Sketchpad.prototype._stroke = function(start, end, color, size) {
  this.context.save();
  if(bErasing){
    this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  }else{
    this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  }
    // if(size === 7 || size === 13){
    //   console.log(size)
    //   this.context.lineJoin = 'square';
    //   this.context.lineCap = 'square';
    // }
    // else{
      this.context.lineJoin = 'round';
      this.context.lineCap = 'round';
    // }
      this.context.strokeStyle = color;
      this.context.lineWidth = size;
    // switch(size){

    //     case 2:
    //     this.context.globalAlpha = 1;
    //     break;
    //     case 7:
    //     this.context.globalAlpha = 0.7;
    //     break;
    //     case 13:
    //     this.context.globalAlpha = 0.4;
    //     break;
    //     default:
    //     this.context.globalAlpha = 0.2;
    // }
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
    this.context.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
    this.context.closePath();
    this.context.stroke();

    this.context.restore();
};

//
// Callback Handlers
//

Sketchpad.prototype._mouseDown = function(event) {
  this._lastPosition = this._cursorPosition(event);
  this._currentStroke.color = this.color;
  this._currentStroke.size = this.penSize;
  this._currentStroke.lines = [];
  // console.log(this._currentStroke.lines)
  this._sketching = true;
  this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this._mouseMove);
};

Sketchpad.prototype._mouseUp = function(event) {
  if (this._sketching) {
    this.strokes.push($.extend(true, {}, this._currentStroke));
    this._sketching = false;
  }
  this.canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', this._mouseMove);
};

Sketchpad.prototype._mouseMove = function(event) {
  var currentPosition = this._cursorPosition(event);

  this._draw(this._lastPosition, currentPosition, this.color, this.penSize);
  this._currentStroke.lines.push({
    start: $.extend(true, {}, this._lastPosition),
    end: $.extend(true, {}, currentPosition),
  });

  this._lastPosition = currentPosition;
};

Sketchpad.prototype._touchStart = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (this._sketching) {
    return;
  }
  this._lastPosition = this._cursorPosition(event.changedTouches[0]);
  this._currentStroke.color = this.color;
  this._currentStroke.size = this.penSize;
  this._currentStroke.lines = [];
  this._sketching = true;
  this.canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', this._touchMove, false);
};

Sketchpad.prototype._touchEnd = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (this._sketching) {
    this.strokes.push($.extend(true, {}, this._currentStroke));
    this._sketching = false;
  }
  this.canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', this._touchMove);
};

Sketchpad.prototype._touchCancel = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (this._sketching) {
    this.strokes.push($.extend(true, {}, this._currentStroke));
    this._sketching = false;
  }
  this.canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', this._touchMove);
};

Sketchpad.prototype._touchLeave = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (this._sketching) {
    this.strokes.push($.extend(true, {}, this._currentStroke));
    this._sketching = false;
  }
  this.canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', this._touchMove);
};

Sketchpad.prototype._touchMove = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var currentPosition = this._cursorPosition(event.changedTouches[0]);

  this._draw(this._lastPosition, currentPosition, this.color, this.penSize);
  this._currentStroke.lines.push({
    start: $.extend(true, {}, this._lastPosition),
    end: $.extend(true, {}, currentPosition),
  });

  this._lastPosition = currentPosition;
};

//
// Public API
//

Sketchpad.prototype.reset = function() {
  // Set attributes
  this.canvas = $(this.element)[0];
  this.canvas.width = this._width;
  this.canvas.height = this._height;
  this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Setup event listeners
  this.redraw(this.strokes);

  if (this.readOnly) {
    return;
  }

  // Mouse
  this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this._mouseDown);
  this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', this._mouseUp);
  this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', this._mouseUp);

  // Touch
  this.canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', this._touchStart);
  this.canvas.addEventListener('touchend', this._touchEnd);
  this.canvas.addEventListener('touchcancel', this._touchCancel);
  this.canvas.addEventListener('touchleave', this._touchLeave);
};

Sketchpad.prototype.drawStroke = function(stroke) {
  for (var j = 0; j < stroke.lines.length; j++) {
    var line = stroke.lines[j];
    this._draw(line.start, line.end, stroke.color, stroke.size);
  }
};
Sketchpad.prototype.erase = function() {
  // this._erase(line.start, line.end, stroke.color, stroke.size);
};

Sketchpad.prototype.redraw = function(strokes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < strokes.length; i++) {
    this.drawStroke(strokes[i]);
  }
};

Sketchpad.prototype.toObject = function() {
  return {
    width: this.canvas.width,
    height: this.canvas.height,
    strokes: this.strokes,
    undoHistory: this.undoHistory,
  };
};

Sketchpad.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return JSON.stringify(this.toObject());
};

Sketchpad.prototype.animate = function(ms, loop, loopDelay) {
  this.clear();
  var delay = ms;
  var callback = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.strokes.length; i++) {
    var stroke = this.strokes[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < stroke.lines.length; j++) {
      var line = stroke.lines[j];
      callback = this._draw.bind(this, line.start, line.end,
                                 stroke.color, stroke.size);
      this.animateIds.push(setTimeout(callback, delay));
      delay += ms;
    }
  }
  if (loop) {
    loopDelay = loopDelay || 0;
    callback = this.animate.bind(this, ms, loop, loopDelay);
    this.animateIds.push(setTimeout(callback, delay + loopDelay));
  }
};

Sketchpad.prototype.cancelAnimation = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.animateIds.length; i++) {
    clearTimeout(this.animateIds[i]);
  }
};

Sketchpad.prototype.clear = function() {
  this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
};

Sketchpad.prototype.undo = function() {
  this.clear();
  var stroke = this.strokes.pop();
  if (stroke) {
    this.undoHistory.push(stroke);
    this.redraw(this.strokes);
  }
};

Sketchpad.prototype.redo = function() {
  var stroke = this.undoHistory.pop();
  if (stroke) {
    this.strokes.push(stroke);
    this.drawStroke(stroke);
  }
};
```

and also having issue while trying the change the texture of brushes according to the pen size.

eraser is working fine and undo is also working fine the only issue is while we erase more than once, then try to undo then last erase is return to real drawing, but other previous works like as the line stroke and display the drawing as per eraser mouse move in canvas.

This is my my function to call above methods:

```js
     var x = "#CB7342",
        y = 2;
    var bErasing = false;
    var canvas, canvasWidth, canvasHeight;
    var ctx;
    var lastPt=null;
    var pathsry = [];
    var points = [];
    var state;
    var colour;
    // past states
    function ySize(size) {

        y = size;
        sketchpad.penSize = y;
    }

    var sketchpad;
    function undo(){
        bErasing = false;
        sketchpad.undo();
        if($('#erase').hasClass('active')){

            bErasing = true;
        }
    }

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('sheet');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var canvasOffset = $('#sheet').offset();
        var parent = canvas.parentNode;
        canvas.width = parent.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = parent.clientHeight;
        // alert(bErasing)
        sketchpad = new Sketchpad({
            element: '#sheet',
            width: canvas.width,
            height: canvas.height,
            color: null,
            penSize: 2,
            globalAlpha: 0.1
        });
    }
    $(document).on('click', "#erase", function () {
        bErasing = true;
    });
```

Comment: `redraw` only ends up calling `_draw` never `_erase`. You are not storing the type of stroke (draw or erase) in the strokes array, thus when you undo and then redraw all the strokes, all erase strokes are drawn as normal strokes "'source-over'" rather than "destination-out". You need to store the type of stroke (draw / erase) with each stroke.

Comment: Thanks for your  response, can you please help me  out for that, I am stucked on that, My last erase working fine  but other are not, I am not using the _erase function I m using only destination-out only in strokes function

Comment: Whether or not you use the argument or a global flag to determine what a stroke is (draw or erase) that state needs to be included in the array of strokes so that when you `Sketchpad.prototype.drawStroke(stroke)` it draws the correct type of stroke.